# Modulus operation

Tags: power-series

I was studying ratio test in infinite sequence. Then I came across this $$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} - l \right| < \epsilon$$ i.e. 
$$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \right| < |l|+\epsilon$$

I don't understand how $| a-b | < c$ becomes $|a| < |b| + c$. Is that a formula?

Answer (score 2):

We have: $|a-b| \geq |a|-|b| \Rightarrow c > |a|-|b| \Rightarrow c+|b| > |a|$

Comment: In Wikipedia, I saw $ | a-b | \geq | (|a| -|b|) |. $

Comment: Isn't $|a-b|\geq |a|-|b|$?

Comment: Please clarify that was it wrong or right, what I saw in Wikipedia? Or is it same?

Answer (score 0):

with $b_n = a_{n+1}/a_n$, you have the starting point
$$|b_n - l|\leq ε $$
Triangle inequality gives
\begin{align}|b_n| &\leq  |b_n - l| + |l|\\
\implies |b_n| &\leq |l| + ε
\end{align}